# Angular: TextArea losing focus each times textarea model gets update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, socket.io

I am using `Socket.io` for brodcasting change to all it subscribers when a data on textarea gets updated but the problem I am having is that when the data gets updated and the `textarea` is in `focus state` it loses all it `focus`. I just want to update the `textarea` only when it is in `blur state` and never on `focus state`.

I tried writing this but it doesnot works

```
<textarea ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}"  ng-model="value.note"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an Alternate solution

```
<textarea ng-blur="saveNote(value)" ng-model="value.note" ></textarea>
```

> In controller

```
app.controller('testController', function($scope){ 
    $scope.persistedValue = '';
    $scope.saveNote = function(value){
       var note = value.note;
       if(note !== $scope.persistedValue){
         //Only save if persistentValue is different from note value  


       }
    }
});
```